# Entity Framework Core and Cosmos DB. Using LINQ expressions to read entities

Tags: c#, azure, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb, entity-framework-core-3.1

In our solution we´re using the package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos 3.1.1` to do operations against our cosmos databases and containers in Azure. We have a fairly easy object structure. An object containg a list of other objects.

```
public class ExampleEntity : Entity
{
    public string TestProperty { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SubEntity> SubEntities { get; set; }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents()
    {
            yield return TestProperty;
    }
}

public class SubEntity : Entity
{
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents()
    {
        yield return IsActive;
    }
}
```

We´ve configured the `DbContext` for EntityFramework like this:

```
builder.Entity<ExampleEntity>().ToContainer(nameof(ExampleEntity));
builder.Entity<ExampleEntity>().HasKey(p => p.id);
builder.Entity<ExampleEntity>().OwnsMany(p => p.SubEntities);
```

The json structure in cosmos looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "51099fa9-5d71-4181-93b1-2c8cc0482a95",
    "CreatedAt": "2020-02-14T08:11:06.701659Z",
    "Discriminator": "ExampleEntity",
    "TestProperty": "Property1",
    "UpdatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "SubEntities": [
        {
            "id": "9a120613-c42a-4399-a660-e6228cfce0ad",
            "CreatedAt": "2020-02-14T08:11:06.70457Z",
            "ExampleEntityid": "51099fa9-5d71-4181-93b1-2c8cc0482a95",
            "IsActive": false,
            "UpdatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": "21b86b53-2d6a-4b31-a60b-8d31cfd04734",
            "CreatedAt": "2020-02-14T08:11:06.705145Z",
            "ExampleEntityid": "51099fa9-5d71-4181-93b1-2c8cc0482a95",
            "IsActive": true,
            "UpdatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
        }
    ],
    "_rid": "R343APAECLsBAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/R343AA==/colls/R343APAECLs=/docs/R343APAECLsBAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"06001f30-0000-0d00-0000-5e46561b0000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1581667867
}
```

Now, we want to search after `ExampleEntities` where `SubEntities` has the boolean value of `IsActive` set to true. This is where our problems starts.

We have a generic repository, where the Read method looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get an entity from the database
/// </summary>
/// <param name="predicate">A predicate to decide which entity to get</param>
/// <param name="children">Child entities to included in the DbSet</param>
/// <returns>All entities that matches the predicate</returns>
public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> ReadAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] children)
{
    var dbSet = _dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
    children.ToList().ForEach(p => dbSet.Include(p));

    var entities = dbSet.Where(predicate);
    return await entities.ToListAsync();
}
```

Using the following code like this in a IntegrationTest:

```
[Test]
public async Task EntityFramework_Should_Return_Object_Based_On_Property_In_SubEntity()
{
    var uow = Container.Resolve<IUnitOfWork<ExampleEntity>>();
    var entity1 = new ExampleEntity
    {
        TestProperty = "Property1",
        SubEntities = new List<SubEntity>
        {
            new SubEntity
            {
                IsActive = false
            },
            new SubEntity
            {
                IsActive = true
            }
        }
    };

    await uow.Repository.CreateAsync(entity1);
    await uow.CommitAsync();

    var readEntity = uow.Repository.ReadAsync(p => p.SubEntities.Any(p => p.IsActive), p => p.SubEntities);
    readEntity.Should().NotBeNull();
}
```

The problem occurs at this line here where I use the Read method from the repository above:

```
var readEntity = uow.Repository.ReadAsync(p => p.SubEntities.Any(p => p.IsActive), p => p.SubEntities);
```

It results in the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<ExampleEntity>
    .Where(e => EF.Property<IEnumerable<SubEntity>>(e, "SubEntities")
        .AsQueryable()
        .Any(o => o.IsActive))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().
```

I find it quite strange that a simple query like this isn´t supported in Entity Framework Cosmos. Obviously I can do a `AsEnumerable()`, but then I will download all the data from the database and do the filtering client side and not on the database side, which will have a huge performance impact when the database contains 100´000s of records..

**How can I rewrite my repository to do such filtering on the database side? Is it possible at all with Entity Framework Cosmos?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [current limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/cosmos/limitations) `Include` and `join` are not supported yet.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. Its really frustrating that it doesnt work in any ORMs when it works when using the SQL API provided by cosmos. I can do the query in the azure portal and get the results that I want. I'd wish Entity Framework Core Cosmos, could implement functionality to supplies raw sql queries. I've tried the FromRawSql, but its not implemented for IQueryable. Do you know any other ways to do so with EF Core? Otherwise I'll switch to something like Cosmonaut or something..

Comment: Have you found any roadmap when Join and Include will be implemented? Couldnt find anything on their GitHub Bug/Feature tracker..

Comment: No news in the EF Core 5.0 previews :'(

Comment: I dont think the link is entierly relevant to the question - neither Join() nor Include() is (explicitly) used when querying embedded documents, they seem to be included by default. Looks more of a translation bug than hitting a known limitation.